# Make codeKit refresh .twig files

Tags: codekit

In the older versions of [Codekit](https://codekitapp.com) you could just add `.twig` to the «Generic file extension» field. Since version 3 this field is gone.

How do I make codekit reload when working on files with the `.twig` extension?